# Nested flexbox height issue in IE

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have nested flexboxes with some images inside, it looks good in Chrome, but in IE you can see the borders on the `flex-item-wrapper` are not flush against the bottom of the image. By the way, in the layout I will sometimes have several `flex-row` with many pictures.

```css
.flex-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-item-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.flex-item {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.picture {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-list">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="flex-item-wrapper">
      <div class="flex-item">
        <a href='#'>
          <img class="picture" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/cartoons/super-mario/clip-art-super-mario-832109.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="flex-item-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="flex-item-wrapper"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know if it applies here but IE has a large number of bugs present: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex and https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be working:

```
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto; /*added*/
}
```

or

```
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%; /*added*/
}
```

See simplified demo:

```css
.flex-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.flex-item {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.picture {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-list">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <a href='#'>
        <img class="picture" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/cartoons/super-mario/clip-art-super-mario-832109.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems due to the nesting flexbox. This fixes it:

```css
.flex-row {
  width: 100%;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```css
.flex-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.flex-item-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.flex-item {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.picture {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="flex-list">
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="flex-item-wrapper">
        <div class="flex-item">
          <a href='#'>
            <img class="picture" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/cartoons/super-mario/clip-art-super-mario-832109.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item-wrapper"></div>
      <div class="flex-item-wrapper"></div>
      <div class="flex-item-wrapper"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, all containers should not extend past the height of the image. Using `align-self: flex-start` does not seem to make the height of the `flex-row` container shrink down to match the height of the image.

Comment: Looks like if I add `height: 100%` to `.flex-row` the problem is fixed.